# Representing child objects in JSON for a mobile API

Tags: json, api, rest, synchronization

I am designing a JSON API for a mobile app and have to decide how to show child objects from the server to the client.  Typically the request from the client to the server will be a single request to sync and the response will include all the objects that need updating. What is the best way to show the objects?

Option A - Nested Children:

```
{ "articles": [
{ "id" : 1,
  "title": "This is the first article",
  "comments": [
      {"id": "1",
       "article_id" : "1",
       "title": "A comment on the first article"
      }]
},
{ "id" : 2,
  "title": "This is the second article",
  "comments": [
      {"id": "2",
       "article_id" : "2",
       "title": "A comment on the second article"
      }]
}, ]}
```

OPTION B - All Objects on Their Own

```
{ "articles": [
  { "id" : 1,
    "title": "This is the first article",
  }
  { "id" : 2,
    "title": "This is the second article",
  }]
 "comments": [
  {"id": "1",
   "article_id" : "1",
   "title": "A comment on the first article"
  },
  {"id": "2",
   "article_id" : "2",
   "title": "A comment on the second article"
  }]}
```

On the client side I can handle either format and build the relationship based on the article_id field so I am not too sure why nest the children, other than that it makes it look nice. However, when I think about writing tests for the client-side, especially the mapping of json to objects it seems easier to show and map each object on its own. I am a beginner here so any thoughts would be helpful.

PS. I am building the server using Rails/Grape and the clients with RestKit/Coredata (iOS) and probably RoboSpice/ORMLite (Android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very subjective. There isn't one correct answer for that. It really depends on whatever approach is more suited to your task and data. You say this is a request used to sync data. How is the data represented and stored on the client side? If flat, like a relational database, then the flat output is probably easier to use. On the other hand, if the client will use the relationships a lot, it's probably better to use the nested structure.

From an API design standpoint, I'd have the endpoint for the articles collection accept a query parameter like `expand`, with a level number, or named entities, and it would add the nested children accordingly. So, for instance, `GET /api/articles?expand=comments` would generate output with nested comments, or `GET /api/articles?expand=1` to generate output with all immediate children. That way, clients can easily generate the nested output if they need it, or they can query the endpoints for articles and comments separately and concatenate the output if they need the flat data.,

Comment: I see. Basically with the expand option you are having your cake and eating it too. A bit more work to manage, but may be worth the optionality.